# CakePHP: How do you list all fields of a model including fields that will be returned in a find with the recursive=2 option?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need a way to show a list of all the columns available to a CakePHP model including the fields from other models/tables that will be returned in Model->find('all', array('recursive' => 2)).  This is for a report builder and the end user gets to select which fields they want included prior to loading any data.

Model->schema() and Model->getColumnTypes() only return the current model's fields, not the extended fields from other models.

How can I get a complete list of fields in a model--including the deep associations provided by 'recursive'=>2 in find?

Comment: Never use recursive greater than 1. Use contain. You should also always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Does using contain make schema() or getFieldTypes() return all the contained fields?

Comment: It by default returns all fields or each relation.

Comment: So I added Containable and it does not add any new fields to the Model->schema() or Model->getColumnTypes().

I get back the same list of fields from only one model.  Extending a generic concept of a blog with three models (Post, Comment, User where Posts HasMany Comments, and Has one User), what I want to get:

`Post.id
Post.topic
Post.body
Post.user_id
Comment.id
Comment.body
Comment.user_id
User.id
User.name`

But all I am getting from Schema() or getColumnTypes() is:

`Post.id
Post.topic
Post.body
Post.user_id`

Comment: Did you use debug=2 or clear the cache?

Comment: debug is 2 and as far as I am aware we're not using any caching at the moment.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept of schema() etc. Those always work on the current object. Of course they don't return related fields. Those related fields and their content are returned when actually retrieving records (after doing actual joins!). If you want all fields, you need to use those methods on each model separately.